# issue with draw a ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to draw a part of one ellipse using `\pgfpatharcto`. However, when I tried to compare with the original complete ellipse, there is a small difference. I attach the code as well as the result.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (2.5cm,0) ellipse (3.5cm and 3.8436cm);

\pgfsetstrokecolor{red}
\pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{2.841cm}{3.8284cm}}
\pgfpatharcto{3.5cm}{3.8436cm}{0}{0}{0}{\pgfpoint{2.841cm}{-3.8284cm}}\pgfusepath{stroke};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wound say this is an rounding error?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am not quite understand your point. Do you have any suggestions to overcome this issue?

Comment: (2.841cm,3.8284) is not on the original ellipse.  Try (2.841cm,3.82531415cm) instead.  2.841=3.5 cos(84.4088847)  3.82531415 = 3.8436 sin(84.4088847).

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, you are right. The point is indeed not on the original ellipse. I need to check further. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's also possible to draw twice the ellipse but inside a clipping scope the  second time:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (2.5cm,0) ellipse (3.5cm and 3.8436cm);

\begin{scope}
\clip (2.5cm,0)--++(80:3.9) arc(80:-80:3.9)--cycle;
\draw[red] (2.5cm,0) ellipse (3.5cm and 3.8436cm);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You might like to try [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) to do this.  It has a useful `subpath` syntax that lets you draw segments of a saved path.
Compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path e;
    e = fullcircle xscaled 3.5cm yscaled 3.8436cm;
    draw e withpen pencircle scaled 2 withcolor .8 white;
    draw subpath (-2,2) of e withcolor 2/3 red;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Metapost provides a concept of "time" along a path.  On a `fullcircle` path, there are 8 points of time starting with point 0 at "3 o'clock" as it were.

So `subpath (0,2) of c` would be from 3 o'clock to midday.  You can use fractional numbers too: `subpath (2.718, 3.1415) of c`.

And as shown in my example you can use negative numbers to refer to points "before" point 0.